# python How to use variables in sql

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a database:

**datas.db** ---> table  bk

- Id     -- *autonumber*
- Name   -- *string*
- Number -- *numeric*
- Timer  -- *string*

**code Python**

```
self.db = sqlite3.connect("library.db")
self.cur = self.db.cursor()

search_name = self.lineEdit_1.text()
name = self.lineEdit_2.text()
number_age = self.lineEdit_3.text()
description = self.lineEdit_4.text()

self.cur.execute("UPDATE bk SET (Name ='?',Number =?, Timer ='?') WHERE Name ='?'",(name,number_age,description,search_name))
self.db.commit()
```

Now I get a syntax error, I've seen that they use this

```
"Name ='%s'"%name)
```

But I do not know how to use it when I have several variables

Comment: try removing the quotes around your question marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [SQLLite Docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) your code should look like.

You query is wrong, change from

```
UPDATE bk SET (Name ='?',Number =?, Timer ='?') WHERE Name ='?'
```

to

```
UPDATE bk SET Name=?, Number=?, Timer=? WHERE Name=?
```

```
self.db = sqlite3.connect("library.db")
self.cur = self.db.cursor()

search_name = self.lineEdit_1.text()
name = self.lineEdit_2.text()
number_age = self.lineEdit_3.text()
description = self.lineEdit_4.text()

self.cur.execute("UPDATE bk SET Name=?, Number=?, Timer=? WHERE Name =?",(name, number_age, description, search_name))
self.db.commit()
```

Comment: Look more carefully at OP code: `self.db = sqlite3.connect`. Although code is SQL-89 and mysql documentation **can** be useful but correct link will be https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: perfect, tank you